# Validating string for possible space returns error in Django form even though there's no space

Tags: python, django

I have two fields in my Django form where I want the user to insert exactly one word. So to have some validation in the view i created the following validator (idea is to search for spaces):

**Views.py**

```
[..]

if ' ' in poller_choice_one or poller_choice_two:
    raise ValidationError(('Limit your choice to one word'), code='invalid')
else:

[..]
```

To make it more robust I added the `strip` option to the FormFields to be validated:

```
    # Poller Choices
    poller_choice_one = forms.CharField(label='Choice one', max_length=20, strip=True)
    poller_choice_two = forms.CharField(label='Choice two', max_length=20, strip=True)
```

I tried like a bunch of inputs from single digits to single chars etc., it always raises the validation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is interpreted as:

```
if (' ' in poller_choice_one) or (poller_choice_two):
    # …
```

it will first check if there is a space in the `poller_choice_one`. If that is not the case it will evaluate the *truthiness* of the `poller_choice_two`. A `str`ing has as truthiness `True` if it contains at least one character. So the `if` condition will be `True` from the moment there is a space in `poller_choice_one`, or `poller_choice_two` has at least one character.

You thus should rewrite the condition to:

```
if ' ' in poller_choice_one or ' ' in poller_choice_two:
    raise ValidationError(('Limit your choice to one word'), code='invalid')
# …
```

Comment: ahh.. thanks Willem! How can someone print this Validation Error on the frontend? Right now the view only returns it in the terminal

Comment: @Jonas: typically you should render that form where the validation error happened in the template. Then it will print error messages next to the form fields that were a problem, and the non-field-specific ones at the top of the form.

Comment: so you mean to add s.th. like return form: form within the if statement of the validation error?

Comment: @Jonas: you `render(request, template, {'form': form})` with `form` the validated form (that turned out to be invalid), if you then render it in the template with `{{ form }}` it will show the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex you could implement this validator:

```
def validate(s0, s1):
    return re.match(" ", s0) or re.match(" ", s1)
```

Example:

```py
poller_choice_one = "hi"
poller_choice_two = "how are you?"

if not validate(poller_choice_one, poller_choice_two):
    raise ValidationError(('Limit your choice to one word'), code='invalid')
```